# Publish image from azure devops multi-stage pipeline to DockerHub

Tags: azure-devops, dockerhub

I'm trying to setup in `Azure DevOps` a `Multi Stage Pipeline`. It works well up to the point where I need to publish the image to my `DockerHub` account. Here is the snippet from my `YAML`:

[image: YAML]

I must admit, I understand why, my credentials are nowhere :) I tried to set it up using `Environments` but the only resource I can add is Kubernetes (not sure why that is)

Any suggestions how to setup authentication with DockerHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `docker login` step:

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: service_connection_name
```

you should put this step before the step you are actually using to push the images

docs on how to create the connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg